# Can you define what it means that a set of functions has a common property?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of functions with a common property. Does this mean that the property is shared pairwise or that the property is shared amongst all elements of $\mathcal{A}$?

For example, what does it mean that a set of polynomials do not have a common zero?

Comment: This is a very good question. I think it's impossible to say which one is intended by the author. I would assume by default that when it's said a set of polynomials do not have a common zero, it means that there is no $a$ such that $p(a)=0$ for all $p$ because in mathematics we usually deal with quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$. The pairwise interpretation is also equally likely. So, it's really ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Generally*, this means that all elements of a set share that property, but it depends on the context a bit. For the polynomial zero question, it is assumed that this means that there is no value $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$ for all $f$ in set $A$